# Curl keeps getting wrong page on yahoo options page

Tags: curl, get, yahoo-finance

As I am trying to access this page on yahoo (*unusually high volume* tab, with 100 rows per page)

http://finance.yahoo.com/options/lists/?mod_id=mediaquotesoptions&tab=tab2&rcnt=100

with command line in Windows 7:

curl.exe -v -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0" http://finance.yahoo.com/options/lists/?mod_id=mediaquotesoptions&tab=tab2&rcnt=100

I keep getting the wrong page (the default *high volume* tab with 50 rows per page) as if tab and rcnt atguments haven't been passed by Curl at all.

I tried all things I can imagine including passing tab and rcnt with POST, changing user agent, etc. and nothing worked. I suspect this has to do with browser detection or session control on yahoo site but don't know where to turn.

Any advice would be highly appreciated!
Bo

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the URL in double-quotes, that should solve the problem you are facing.